# Wildfly does not pass intermediate certificate to HTTPS client

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, wildfly

So I have this certificate chain made of 3 certificates:

- Root cert (installed in all clients)
- Intermediate cert (installed in my browser, but not in other clients/Java apps accessing webservices)
- Domain wildcard certificate

Wildfly is configured to use a keystore that holds intermediate and domain certificates  in JKS format, along with the private key for the domain cert. When I send a HTTPS request from my browser, the certificate is validated just fine and everything seems OK. But when the Java client application I am working on tries to establish a connection, it cannot build a valid certificate chain:
`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

I checked the certificates delivered by Wildfly using openssl (`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect <servername>`) and confirmed that the intermediate certificate is NOT transmitted even though it is present in the keystore. Now I can work around this in my development environment by adding the intermediate cert to my local trust store, however that is not an acceptable long-term solution for production.

In my Wildfly's standalone.xml I have specified the keystore and the alias of the wildcard certificate.

```
<server-identities>
  <ssl>
    <keystore path="/path/to/keytsore.jks" keystore-password="supersecure" alias="*.redacted.com"/>
  </ssl>
</server-identities>
```

Searching through the Wildfly admin docs I saw no mention of intermediate certificates. I tried to add an additional  element to the config (same path and password, but alias of the intermediate certificate), but Wildfly would not start up with that.

Any idea how I can get Wildfly to present the intermediate certificate to connecting clients? Does it need to have a specific alias name? Or is there another way to tell Wildfly the alias of any intermediate cert?

Comment: In many environments Wildfly is behind some load balancer/reverse proxy, so Wildfly's client would be under your control. That could serve as workaround, yet it does not change which certificate Wildfly transmits.

Comment: Another keyword might be 'certificate chain'. I found this https://medium.com/@hasnat.saeed/setup-ssl-https-on-jboss-wildfly-application-server-fde6288a0f40, and it seems they import the intermediate CA and store all in a PKCS12 type keystore.

Comment: Sounds like in the keystore you have the intermediate cert as it's own entry rather than as part of a chain with the alias you reference

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri I am accessing it directly without a reverse proxy in between. I do not see why it would work with PKCS#12 rather than JKS, but it is something I have not tried yet.

Comment: @WillT Yes, the intermediate cert has its own entry in the keystore. Can I import multiple certs in one entry?